# Can JMX be used to Monitor TIBCO Rendzevous

Tags: jmx, tibco, tibco-rv

We would like to monitor TIBCO Rendzevous using JMX. Is it possible , if yes, How we can do it.

Answer (score 1):

Write a wrapper around the tibco API classes and expose that wrapper via JMX.